# How to add .class in java Program?

Tags: java, json, class, jackson

How to add `Animal.class` in this class . it is giving the compile time error on eclipse.

on clicking

```
mapper.readValue(jsonInput, Animal.class);
```

eclipse is asking configure build your path. how to to that in test2 package i have all classes.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import test2.*;
    public class Foo
    {
      static String jsonInput = 
          "{\"type\":\"dog\",\"name\":\"Spike\"}";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Animal animal = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, Animal.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(animal));
      }
    }


class Animal  
{  
  public String type;  
  public String name;  
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  If I take your code and remove the `ObjectMapper` references and just have `Animal animal = new Animal()` then it works. Your problems appears not to be related to `Animal`, but perhaps to `ObjectMapper`...

Comment: Not sure if you have imported the `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` before use.

Comment: Encountered same thing. Eclipse shows error and tells to Configure build-path. Tried all possibilities (like imported all jars, removed all unused jars, remove unused imports, try catch etc). Nothing worked. Did u corrected it?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have correctly imported jackson's mapper. (Successful compilation of a `new ObjectMapper()` )

Try defining Animal into a separate .java file, then the mapper should understand what you want to do as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: `Animal` is **not** defined as either a subclass or an inner class.  It's simply a non-public class defined in the same file as `Foo`. It *will* be compiled into `Animal.class`.

Comment: A good practice would be to use an instance of Animal as a model instead of trying to access the .class directly. I saw in jackson's doc that you can also use an instance, it should work better, or at least look better :)

Comment: @Jackson how to add Animal.class in java

Answer (score 0):

You are using ObjectMapper , which is not in jdk.
in order to use this add dependancy jar,
in your case ** dependency meight be missing**

if using maven project add following entry in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

or download jar from 
[jackson-mapper-asl Link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/0.9.7/jackson-mapper-asl-0.9.7.jar) and [Jackson0.7 jar Link](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/jvnet/hudson/jackson/jackson/0.7/jackson-0.7.jar)

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you try to [importing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/pdf/files/workshop/JavaKeywordReference.pdf) 'Animal' Class.